# How to remove 'NULL' from results of queries SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, null

I have a table with 59 columns and over 17K rows. Lots of the rows have `NULL` in some of the columns.

I want to remove the `NULL` so that queries return a blank (`''`) rather than a `NULL`.

Can I run some update function that replaces all `NULL` with `''` ?

Using SQL Server 2008R2 Management Studio.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET column_1 = REPLACE (column_1,NULL,'')
```

But that would take forever to do it to all 59 columns!

What's the trick, team?

Comment: Your `replace()` would not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the SQL standard [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    column_1 = COALESCE(column_1,'')
     , column_2 = COALESCE(column_2,'')
     ...
WHERE  column_1 IS NULL OR
       column_2 IS NULL OR
       ...                  -- avoid empty updates
;
```

Then use `ALTER TABLE ...` to add `NOT NULL` constraints to all columns that shall not have NULL to prohibit re-introducing NULL values.

Don't use <strike>`ISNULL`</strike>, which basically is a duplication of the standard `COALESCE` in some RDBMS - and not available in others. (Well, there are subtle differences, [read the manual for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [even more detail here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull).)

Of course, the empty string (`''`) is only valid for string types. Not for number types, for instance.

Answer (score 7):

Use isnull function. Returns specified value if null is found in column

```
Select isnull(col1,'')
```

Comment: This is a useful feature, which I will use elsewhere, but not what I was looking for today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET column1 = ' '  WHERE column1 = NULL
```